# Simple import of an MS-SQL table into System.Data.DataTable, is this possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When checking [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataSet);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) about `System.Data.DataSet` and `System.Data.DataTable`, I have the impression that "importing an MS-SQL table into C# classes" happens as follows:

- Open the connection
- Write an SQL query in an `SqlCommand`, containing the name of the table, the names of the columns: `SELECT ProductID, SupplierID FROM dbo.Products` (or `SELECT *`), but still the corresponding `SqlDataReader` must be run through for getting the values inside the table).

Isn't there some way to say:

```
DataTable dt_Products = new DataTable(connection, "Products")
```

... and this `DataTable` automatically has the right column names, column types, values, autoincrement properties if possible, ... (without needing to pass by `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`, ...)?

Comment: No. You don't *import* SQL Server tables at all. You load DataTable instances with the result of queries. It makes no sense trying to load a 1M row table into memory when you only want 10 rows that match some criteria. The docs make this quite clear

Comment: You should try to understand how ADO.NET works in general before trying to use specific classes. DataTable is more-or-less obsolete now that everyone uses ORMs or micro-ORMs like Dapper to map directly to objects. The important classes are  SqlCommand and SqlDataReader, not DataTable and SqlDataAdapter. SqlCommand is used by *every* other library to retrieve data. SqlDataReader is used to read the results. `DataTable.Load(reader)` will read the schema and the data from SqlDataReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is this.

```
using (var da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductID, SupplierID FROM dbo.Products", connection)) 
{
 da.Fill(dt_Products);
}
```

Comment: This is great! I have replaced your query by `"SELECT * FROM ..."` and not only the `Rows`, but also the `Columns` are filled in correctly, even with their datatype filled in.